# What is the path for Android database file?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to find the path for the android database files on Ubuntu 10.4, because I want to access with SQLite Browser. Someone can tell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, the database that you create for an application is only accessible to itself; other applications will not be able to access it.

- Once created, the SQLite database is stored in the **`/data/data/<package_name>/databases`**  folder of an Android device.

  **`How to see the database file`**:

  If you are using **`Eclipse`**:
  switch to DDMS perspective - > File Browser -> Browse to data/data/your_package_name
  folder. There you would see your database.

  (To open DDMS Perspective, go to **`window -> open Perspective -> DDMS`**)
- And also you can use the **`adb shell`** to **cd** to that directory and open the **`db with sqlite3`**.

You can also copy files or database from Android devices or from emulator by using **`adb pull`** , for more info refer this: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#copyfiles

Comment: I've done this, but there is no files in File Explorer. It doesnt show anything. why?

Comment: @psyhclo are you using real device or phone ? AFAIK, when emulator is running, at that time data/data folder is definately showing

Answer (score 0):

The path of your application database?

You will have to pull it from the emu/cel.

I would recommend using [questoidsqlitemanager](http://code.google.com/p/questoidsqlitemanager/):

> Questoid SQLite Manager is built on
>   top of Dalvik Debug Monitor Server
>   (DDMS). This tool is intended for
>   Android developers to manage SQLite db
>   file on Android device emulator.